# Ajax cross platform request issue using jsonp

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to develop a web-app with Producteev APIs using **PHP**+**jQuery**. 
As shown in the above image, the official documentation says that you have to handle the call to the given link. 
*Source >* https://www.producteev.com/api/doc/#AuthenticationOAuth20Flows

[image]

So, using PHP and jQuery, I created an ajax request with type GET but the answer, when Producteev redirected the user to the correct **Reditect URI**, was

[image]

So I tried using `dataType: jsonp` and `crossDomain: true` as parameters in the ajax call, in my request as a solution, but as said in the documentation, the Producteev server answers a *json*. 
I tried another solution, that's putting the code `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` in my PHP, at the top of the index.php page, but nothing changed.

Can someone help me figuring out a solution? Thanks a lot.

Comment: If the API does not respond with CORS headers then you cannot make a request to it through JS code. What you are attempting to do is not possible. You will have to make the request server side.

Comment: If you Google the issue the API vendor has been asked about this before. Their solution was to proxy the requests from JS to your own server, then on to Producteev: https://community.jivesoftware.com/thread/273068

Comment: _“I tried another solution, that's putting the code header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); in my PHP, at the top of the index.php page, but nothing changed”_ – of course not. The _remote_ party that you want to request data _from_ has to issue this header, they are the ones to decide whether your page is allowed to access their data cross-domain, not you.

Comment: Google CORS or Access-Control-Allow-Origins. The headers have to be added server side. See https://www.moesif.com/blog/technical/cors/Authoritative-Guide-to-CORS-Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing-for-REST-APIs/